# bootstrap multiple nav tabs for tab content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a type of pagination for bootstrap tab, i figured an easy approach would be to create two nav tabs with html and then try to style the second nav up to look like the carousel pagination. However im currently having problems trying to implement it so that both nav-tabs work together. As I can't manage to get it so if I click on one tab the other will appear active.

**[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3x6ekc5s/3/)** however I can't manage to get it working correctly.

```
<div>

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">1</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">2</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">3</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">4</div>
</div>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

what I essentially want to achieve is that the top nav and bottom nav of the tab systems will automatically update (with the class active) depending on the content selected. Would this be achieved by javascript?

Comment: sorry about but what i essentially want to achieve is that the top nav and bottom nav of the tab systems will automatically update (with the class active) depending on the content selected. Would this be achieved by javascript?

Comment: That would be achieved using javascript... you would need to change the classes (and content) when you click on the top navigation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click on a tab, record the href value. Then select all nav tabs with the matching href and set them to active. This will keep the top and bottom navs in sync with each other no matter which one you click. Finally set the matching tab to active.

[Updated JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/3x6ekc5s/8/)

```
$('.nav-tabs li a').click(function (e) {     
    //get selected href
    var href = $(this).attr('href');    

    //set all nav tabs to inactive
    $('.nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');

    //get all nav tabs matching the href and set to active
    $('.nav-tabs li a[href="'+href+'"]').closest('li').addClass('active');

    //active tab
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
    $('.tab-pane'+href).addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: hi sorry to bringing this up again, but if i use 'fade' into nav? how to generate fade in fade out effect? i tried to add class fade and so on but it just can't work if i using it with the code above...

Answer (score 1):

I found that when using the fade effect (i.e. `class="fade"`), the answer by @Brino would not apply the fade transition. After reading through the bootstrap code and documentation, I found that I could call the `$().tab('show)` on the anchor tag and all tabs would update accordingly. See the following code snippet.

```js
$('.nav-tabs li a').click(function (e) {     
    //get selected href
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    
    // show tab for all tabs that match href
    $('.nav-tabs li a[href="' + href + '"]').tab('show');
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>

        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>

        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">1</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">2</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">3</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">4</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>

        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>

        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for this solution for bootstrap@5.2.3, here is my solution:

```js
$('.nav-pills button').click(function() {  
  var $selector = $('.nav-pills button[data-bs-target="' + $(this).attr("data-bs-target") + '"]').not(this);
  var nav = $selector.closest('.nav-pills');
  nav.find('button').removeClass("active");
  $selector.addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab" tabindex="0">Content 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab" tabindex="0">Content 2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab" tabindex="0">Content 3</div>
</div>
<br/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab2" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```