# Bootstrap 5 - two navs one tab-content

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-tabs

I have code consisting of three identical blocks, each with at least two nav and one tab-content. The problem is that I can't make it so that when I click on an item to deselect the active item in the other list

I found a similar solution for bootstrap 3, but I can't translate it correctly for bootstrap 5, I'm not good with scripts.
[bootstrap multiple nav tabs for tab content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893353/bootstrap-multiple-nav-tabs-for-tab-content)
[another solution for BS3](https://jsfiddle.net/AmitKB/kv8yLL08/)

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="MyTabPillsOne">
  <div class="hr-text hr-text-left m-t-2 m-b-1">
    <h6><strong>List 1</strong></h6>
  </div>
  <div class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <button class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#tab-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-3" aria-selected="true">1</button>
      <button class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#tab-2" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-3" aria-selected="false">2</button>
      <button class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#tab-3" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-3" aria-selected="false">3</button>
  </div>

  <div class="hr-text hr-text-left m-t-2 m-b-1">
    <h6><strong>List 2</strong></h6>
  </div>
  <div class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <button class="nav-link " data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#tab-a" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-a" aria-selected="false">a</button>
      <button class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#tab-b" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-b" aria-selected="false">b</button>
      <button class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#tab-c" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-c" aria-selected="false">c</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-1">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-3">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-a">
      <h1>A</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-b">
      <h1>B</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-c">
      <h1>C</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So do you want clicking an element to deselect the active item in the other list, or sync those lists?

Comment: Yes I want clicking an element to deselect the active item in the other list

Comment: If you want to use the native bootstrap js to control which elements are "active", you can not have two separate nav-pills tablist separated in html but grouped together. You could easily use js to control which are active and the response. The other option is to hook into the bootstrap js events, which still requires writing js. Another option, that might be better for you, make one list of nav-links but position them differently. So they appear to be separated, but are not.

Comment: Not possible to create one single list. Both lists are in different parts of the code (in the accordeon collapse)

Answer (score 0):

After reading documentation, I wrote this script:

```
function selectorFlow(selector) {
    document
        .querySelectorAll(
            "." + selector + ' .nav-link[data-bs-toggle="pill"]'
        )
        .forEach((t, i) => {
            t.addEventListener("show.bs.tab", function (e) {
                var active = document.querySelector(
                    "." + selector + " .nav-link.active"
                );
                active.classList.remove("active");
            });
        });
}

selectorFlow("MyTabPillsOne");
selectorFlow("MyTabPillsTwo");
selectorFlow("MyTabPillsThree");
```

The solution is not ideal, but the deadline was tight.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for bootstrap@5.2.3

```js
$('.nav-pills button').click(function() {  
  var $selector = $('.nav-pills button[data-bs-target="' + $(this).attr("data-bs-target") + '"]').not(this);
  var nav = $selector.closest('.nav-pills');
  nav.find('button').removeClass("active");
  $selector.addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab" tabindex="0">Content 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab" tabindex="0">Content 2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab" tabindex="0">Content 3</div>
</div>
<br/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab2" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```