# Tab selection with custom buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have used the tabs in the bootstrap library for my site template.

Tabs work well without any issues. Only I want to connect a button to each tab in addition to clicking on it to go to the same tab by clicking on it.

The reason for doing this is that as the content increases, the user does not have to scroll up to see other tabs and go to other tabs through the buttons I placed at the end of the content.

Also, I don't want the page to refresh by clicking the buttons. I want to go to the desired tab by clicking on each button.

```js
    const triggerTabList = document.querySelectorAll('#myTab a')
    triggerTabList.forEach(triggerEl => {
      const tabTrigger = new bootstrap.Tab(triggerEl)

      triggerEl.addEventListener('click', event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        tabTrigger.show()
      })
    })

    document.querySelector('#myTab > li:first-child a').click()
```

```css
.content_main {
  width: 650px;
  border: 1px solid #00000033;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.nav_main .active {
  background: #6464ff;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav_main div .active {
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
}

.content-tab {
  border: none;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  background: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #00000033;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 #2196f3;
  padding: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a.comment {
  margin: 0;
  border-right: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a.num-comment {
  border-left: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.content-tab {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.content-tab a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content-comment {
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.all_btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f7ff00;
  background: #3568ff;
  padding: 10px 10px 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.all_btn:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f7ff00;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav_main">
      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs content-tab" role="tablist" id="myTab">
        <li role="presentation" class="content-desc"><a class="desc" href="#desc" aria-controls="desc" role="tab"
            data-toggle="tab">content</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="content-author"><a class="author" href="#author" aria-controls="author"
            role="tab" data-toggle="tab">author</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="content-comment"><a class="comment" href="#comment" aria-controls="comment"
            role="tab" data-toggle="tab">comment</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="content-tag"><a class="tag" href="#tag" aria-controls="tag" role="tab"
            data-toggle="tab">tag</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content content_main">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="desc">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero accusantium odit illum aspernatur sit,
            laudantium tempora non odio natus deserunt iure, at inventore laborum sequi asperiores porro culpa,
            repellendus earum tenetur nobis suscipit qui? Totam fugiat illo veniam omnis provident asperiores distinctio
            cumque ab aperiam eaque recusandae labore repellat quae iure corporis eos, quas molestiae a vel neque
            numquam, quibusdam ullam similique! Nemo placeat impedit repellat, perferendis praesentium quidem quis
            exercitationem? Laboriosam impedit atque, ut praesentium nulla placeat. Alias nobis facilis voluptas non ex
            corporis qui velit adipisci sit delectus aut incidunt ut voluptate exercitationem dolor, harum doloremque
            et, rerum sed aperiam nemo. Reiciendis, et aliquid beatae, voluptatum expedita optio fuga esse
            necessitatibus cumque enim qui inventore, veniam voluptates minima neque aliquam commodi dolores accusantium
            reprehenderit laboriosam ad assumenda natus libero. Praesentium, excepturi magnam. Accusamus excepturi iusto
            modi earum. Dolorum libero id, atque sequi rem at ducimus soluta minima quam earum, eum aliquam delectus
            nostrum nihil aliquid repellendus laboriosam, aut sit. Ea saepe distinctio voluptatibus, hic molestias,
            dolore illum, nostrum voluptatem a nisi velit nam deserunt. Doloribus, quaerat? Dignissimos amet expedita
            provident dolorem qui. Qui perferendis laudantium exercitationem sit soluta sequi eligendi, molestias,
            suscipit architecto, nemo sunt perspiciatis recusandae fugit!
          </p>
          <a id="btn_author" class="all_btn" href="#author"><span class="fas fa-pencil"></span> author</a>
          <a id="btn_comment" class="all_btn" href="#comment"><span class="fas fa-comment"></span> comment</a>
          <a id="btn_tag" class="all_btn" href="#tag"><span class="fas fa-tag"></span> tag</a>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="author">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, impedit!
          </p>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="comment">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugit unde incidunt earum itaque aperiam
            nemo tenetur adipisci, ex hic.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tag">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci dicta repellendus doloremque voluptatum
            omnis, impedit commodi nihil ad! Dolore, alias.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: See: [Bootstrap 5 - two navs one tab-content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74906305/22152755)

Comment: Hi. I checked this answer. But that's not what I want to do. I have edited the **libraries** in my question so that you can better understand what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. Is there a difference between Bootstrap 5 and Bootstrap 5.3 in tabs?

Comment: No, they are not different. Only the `<button>` tag is not used in my code, and with the `<a>` tag, I want to connect to the `<div>` tag, which contains other content, without refreshing the page.

Comment: That's what the other code does too - does it refresh the page? No, it doesn't. You can also edit it to your custom needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your button this way:

```html
<div class="tab-content content_main">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="desc">
    ...

    <a id="btn_author" class="all_btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#author"><span class="fas fa-pencil"></span> author</a>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="author">
...
  </div>
...
  </div>
```

```js
$('#btn_author').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#myTab a[href="#author"]').tab('show');
  });
```